# How to suppress warning output in CruiseControl.net

Tags: visual-studio, cruisecontrol.net

I am using cruisecontrol.net to build and deploy as part of the continuous integration. During the build process, it shows many warnings as shown below:

Read-only property "CCNetLabel" cannot be overwritten.
Log\ILogRecord.cs(10,18): warning CS0108: 'My.Interface.Log.ILogRecord.Level' hides inherited member 'My.Interface.Log.ILogTuple.Level'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. [d:\Build\mysite\abc\Technology.Interface\Teach.Interface.csproj]

These are benign warnings with no bearing on the build process. Is there a way to suppress them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these parameters in your msbuild task in your ccnet.config file. It passes these to the msbuild executable.

```
<buildArgs>/consoleloggerparameters:ErrorsOnly /verbosity:minimal</buildArgs>
```

They are documented in the msbuild command line reference
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx